# Mutable objects in imported modules

Tags: python

I read that importing a module's mutable objects and changing them in-place,affects the original imported module's objects as well.
For instance:

```
from mymod import x
x[0]=1001
```

So when I do this:

```
import mymod
print(mymod.x)
```

Prints [1001,43,bla].
My question is,does an in-place change this affect a module's compiled byte code,a module's source(unlikely isn't it?) or the namespace that I've imported?So if I change something like that,import at a later time the same module somewhere else and try to access the mutable object,what would I get?Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. When you import that module at a later time (or if another script imports the module at the same time your program is still running) you get your own, "clean" copy of that module.

So if the  `test.py` contains the single line `x = [1,2,3]`, you get:

```
>>> from test import x
>>> x[0] = 1001
>>> x
[1001, 2, 3]
>>> import test
>>> test.x
[1001, 2, 3]
>>> imp.reload(test)
<module 'test' from 'test.py'>
>>> test.x   # test is rebound to a new object 
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x        # the old local variable isn't affected, of course
[1001, 2, 3]
```

Comment: So this effect is valid only during one single import right?A reload would reset everything?

Comment: Other modules that import the modified module will see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Changes made to a module at run-time are not saved back to disk, but they are active until Python quits:

test.py

```
stuff = ['dinner is?']
```

test1.py

```
from test import stuff
stuff.append('pizza!')
```

test2.py

```
from test import stuff
```

interactive prompt:

```
--> import test
--> test.stuff
['dinner is?']
--> import test1
--> test.stuff
['dinner is?', 'pizza!']
--> import test2
--> test2.stuff
['dinner is?', 'pizza!']
--> test.stuff
['dinner is?', 'pizza!']
```